# Htaccess alias domains - http redirect main domain, https work fine

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have one domain and 1 alias domain and in htaccess I put this rules:

```
#Domain: www.domain1.ro
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain1.ro$
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api$ api/ [L]

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

# Dispatcher
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain1.ro$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain1.ro$
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]


#Domain: www.domain2.ro
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.ro$
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api$ api/ [L]

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]


# Dispatcher
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.ro$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.ro$
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

The problem is when I put in browser: http://domain2.ro -> (redirect https://domain1.ro). If I use https://domain2.ro work fine.

Domain1 is the main domain and domain2 is alias domain. (the same root - It`s Prestashop with 2 shops).

I want to keep the URL from both domains if I use HTTP or HTTPS (not only https).

Comment: I don’t see anything that would cause a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS in the code you have shown. I’m guessing this is probably rather due to PrestaShop settings.

Comment: I think the problem is here but I am not sure: RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/] . Only when I acces alias domain with http:// (not https), I got redirect to primary domain.

Comment: But that should just get you relative substitution URLs starting with a /, don’t see how that would make it “hop domains”. Check the settings for the alias domain in your hosting panel, whether that is not perhaps set to redirect to the main domain. If that’s not it, PrestaShop could be the culprit here as well, I think there’s a domain and an SSL domain in the settings there. If you have PS also set to redirect to HTTPS, then it will take the latter setting.